# Hi! when I export in gltf format this error appears V3.3.1

Tags: modeling, python, export, add-on, gltf

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\3.3\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\__init__.py", line 648, in execute
    return gltf2_blender_export.save(context, export_settings)
  File "E:\3.3\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_export.py", line 35, in save
    json, buffer = __export(export_settings)
  File "E:\3.3\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_export.py", line 52, in __export
    __gather_gltf(exporter, export_settings)
  File "E:\3.3\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_export.py", line 66, in __gather_gltf
    active_scene_idx, scenes, animations = gltf2_blender_gather.gather_gltf2(export_settings)
  File "E:\3.3\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather.py", line 30, in gather_gltf2
    scenes.append(__gather_scene(blender_scene, export_settings))
  File "E:\3.3\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 38, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\3.3\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather.py", line 69, in __gather_scene
    node = gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.gather_node(
  File "E:\3.3\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 35, in gather_node
    mesh=__gather_mesh(vnode, blender_object, export_settings),
  File "E:\3.3\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 246, in __gather_mesh
    result = gltf2_blender_gather_mesh.gather_mesh(blender_mesh,
  File "E:\3.3\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 38, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\3.3\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_mesh.py", line 61, in gather_mesh
    primitives=__gather_primitives(blender_mesh, uuid_for_skined_data, vertex_groups, modifiers, materials, export_settings),
  File "E:\3.3\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_mesh.py", line 147, in __gather_primitives
    return gltf2_blender_gather_primitives.gather_primitives(blender_mesh,
  File "E:\3.3\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 38, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\3.3\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_primitives.py", line 83, in gather_primitives
    material = gltf2_blender_gather_materials.gather_material(
  File "E:\3.3\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 38, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\3.3\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_materials.py", line 57, in gather_material
    extensions, uvmap_actives_extensions = __gather_extensions(blender_material, emissive_factor, export_settings)
  File "E:\3.3\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_materials.py", line 250, in __gather_extensions
    specular_extension, use_actives_uvmap_specular = export_specular(blender_material, export_settings)
  File "E:\3.3\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_materials_specular.py", line 124, in export_specular
    specular_color = (1 - transmission) * (1 / f0_from_ior) * 0.08 * specular * tint_strength + transmission * tint_strength
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

[image: Export sittings 1]

[image]

The error appears only with gltf format. I tried obj and fbx and that worked.

Blend file link: [google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ngiMCBBUXXkSeEhozRhMFpChZ4CutG_z/view?usp=share_link)

And thank you for taking some of your time to read this <3

Comment: What happens when you import the exported fbx and try to export it as gltf? Also, the access to your file is denied.

Comment: Hi, mqbaka first of all thank you for your time and effort in helping me <3, I did what you suggested exporting in fbx and trying to export it as gltf and it worked so thank you so much, but the models that I imported in the original file didn't export to the fbx file but Ill try to find a solution for that and thanks again and I fixed the link issue now you can access the file

Comment: I downloaded your file and exported a gltf and I didn't see any problem (at least no porblem while exporting). I don't know what's causing the problem for you, I couldn't reproduce it. I used all the settings you showed in the screenshot and it went well. I used 3.2.2

Comment: Maybe the version difference I'll try to download the same version as yours and see if that fixes the problem, and I'll be so glad if you upload that glft file and sent me the link in case it didn't work and thanks <3

Comment: You can have it https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fmEu_jVkc_VdalUmAElFLu7bqjHu8tlf/view?usp=sharing I tried to export with and without camera and lights so there are 2 glb files there. Also I would like to note that your file contains multiple animation data and it may come out buggy in some platforms if you don't clean up the blend file a bit before exporting to gltf but I guess that's not the topic for this question.

Comment: Hi mqbaka: first of all thanks for the link and highlighting the animation issue it seems that the version difference caused the problem maybe there is a bug in the new version cause it worked fine with the older version with no problem so thanks again have a nice day

Comment: I'm glad I helped.

Comment: Special thanks to [mqbaka mqbaka](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/115533/mqbaka-mqbaka)
for helping me resolving this issue and just like he said the version difference was the issue, I tried to mark his comment as an answer but I couldn't there is no button to do so like stack overflow.